# Convert PDF book to IPhone App

Tags: iphone, pdf

Can any one suggest me the best way to convert PDF to IPhone App?

Answer (score 3):

1. Learn objective c
2. Get an iPhone developer license
3. Carefully break up your pdf into images and text
4. Write code to display the images and text in an attractive way
5. Design some cool icons
6. Publish to the App store
7. Wait for approval
8. Done!

Comment: +1: i agree with all except #3. you can use CGPDF to display a pdf fairly attractively these days. :)